# HTTP ERROR: 404 NOT_FOUND RequestURI=/solr/admin/ Powered by jetty://

Tags: solr

I work on windows 7.
version of symfony: symfony 1.4

I have downloaded tjSolrDoctrineBehaviorPlugin After unzipping I cd into `"C:\wamp\www\mon_projet\plugins\tjSolrDoctrineBehaviorPlugin\lib\vendor\solr"` and then run `java-jar start.jar`. The following message comes up when  I go to http:localhost:8983/solr/admin I then get:

```
HTTP ERROR: 404
NOT_FOUND
RequestURI=/solr/admin/
Powered by jetty://
```

I downloaded the plugin from (github) : https://github.com/thibault/tjSolrDoctrineBehaviorPlugin

I apply the steps found in tutorial (readme): http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/tjSolrDoctrineBehaviorPlugin

can you help me please to solve this problem? and thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Please post your question in english so everyone can read and understand it, and you can be helped.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Solr did you install?

Check paths because Solr 4+ sets up 3 cores named default, development and test like...
`http://localhost:8982/solr/#/default/query`

`http://localhost:8982/solr/#/development/query`

`http://localhost:8982/solr/#/test/query`